# Stretch Image only if larger

Tags: css

I'm trying to brush up on css and want to know if this is possible with css only:

Let's say I have an image that I want to display in a `100x100` pixel div tag. I'm not sure what the image will be, but if it's smaller than `100x100` pixels, I want it to center the image. If the image is larger, I want it to shrink it to the size of the of the window.

For instance if it's larger:

[image]

And if it's smaller:

[image]

**Is this possible with css alone?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, not a problem. Try this:

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px solid #999;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
}
img {
    max-width:100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/200" />
</div>

<div>
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/50/50" />
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jqkFp/)** with two images, one 50x50 and the other 200x200

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

CSS

```
div {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
<img src="image source1" alt="enter image description here">
</div>
<br>
<div>
<img src="image source2" alt="enter image description here">
</div>
```

And the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ufc5p/)

The top image is originally 100px by 100px and the bottom is originally 75px by 75px.

***Edit***

Oops, had my CSS backwards on the fiddle. It's updated now.